# Change User from bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a user "chad"

I am logging into linux machine with user "server"

I am creating a script and try to add below command

```
 sudo su -s /bin/bash chad
```

so I can get into user chad and execute rest of my commands from this script
How do I do that?

Below Is My script

```
   #!/bin/bash

   exec /bin/su -s /bin/bash chad - << 'EOF'

   echo "pwd"
   pwd

   cd /home/chad/py2.0/test/py_it/


   echo "git branch"
   git branch



   read -p "Are you sure about branch? (yes/no)" reply

   choice=$(echo $reply|sed 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/')

   if [ "$choice" = 'yes' ] 
   then
   echo "Welcome you selected yes, wait for 3 seconds to get output";
   sleep 3;
   echo "git pull for py2.0";
   "git pull origin integration/py2.0";

   elif [ "$choice" = 'no'  ]
   then

   echo "You selected 'no', hence exiting in 3 seconds";
   sleep 3
   exit 0
   else
   echo "invalid answer, type yes or no";
   fi
   EOF
```

Below is Output

```
   git branch
  * integration/py2.0
   master
  invalid answer, type yes or no
```

Comment: Does that not work ?

Comment: If this doesnt work, did you try to export user into your script? `export $USER=chad` or you can use `setenv`

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the following line in your script:
`exec sudo -u chad /bin/sh - << 'EOF'`

All commands after this line will be under chad user

Check it with this:

```
id
exec sudo -u chad /bin/sh - << 'EOF'
id
id
id
EOF
```

Comment: not working .when i use exec sudo -u /bin/bash chad - << eof  it changes the user but no other commands works in scrips

Comment: could you please give us more details

Comment: for example 
insert : 
id    
id    
id    
right after command

Comment: Script = #!/bin/bash
exec su -s /bin/bash chad - << eof
echo "pwd"
cd
cd chad_py2.0/chad_cloud/
echo "git branch"
git branch

read -p "Are you sure about branch? " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
echo "git pull for py2.0"

Comment: output =  sudo ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 35: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `eof')
pwd
git branch
* integration/py2.0
  master
bash: line 14: cho: command not found
bash: line 15: conditional binary operator expected
bash: line 15: syntax error near `^[Yy]$'
bash: line 15: `if [[  =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]'

Comment: Please post example with simple `id ` to be sure that command doesn't work.

Comment: Please add output for test from my answer

Comment: Below is output

uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
uid=106(chad) gid=1000(server) groups=1000(server),27(sudo),114(chad)
uid=106(chad) gid=1000(server) groups=1000(server),27(sudo),114(chad)
uid=106(chad) gid=1000(server) groups=1000(server),27(sudo),114(chad)

Comment: So , it did exact what you are looking for. before `sudo` you are `root` after you are `chad`.  Don't forger to add `EOF` to your real scritp

Comment: I did, See above script I added, When I added read -p for Yes/No in bash script is didn't worked.

Comment: @JaydeepChaudhari Please correct your question, here is problem not only in changing user in shell. Please attach full/part of your script to the main question

Comment: Question Updated with the script.

Comment: @Arseniye, Any positive way to nail down issue for mentioned script in question?